# Выбор сервиса карт для сайта недвижимости

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-служба, карты

Как подключить к сайту недвижимости такой сервис, чтобы пользователи, которые добавляют объявление, могли указать расположение недвижимости на картах? Google нормального ничего не выдаёт.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно прочитать какую-то документацию о том, как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйся картами от яндекса, там документация на русском и примеров куча  http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/intro/concepts/intro.xml